# Use /boot for windows and grub?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

So, I'm about to wipe everything on my SSD and install everything from scratch.

Last time I tried to install Ubuntu, I remember that it asked for a /boot partition for grub to be installed, and I thought, does Windows have a /boot partition where I can install both, grub and have the Windows Boot manager? Or even better, can I use an already existing partition for windows to use as /boot?

Usually when I do dual boot, I tend to have this partition scheme:

```
sda
├─ sda1  boot (1G)
├─ sda2  EFI System (100M)
├─ sda3  Microsoft reserved (16M)
├─ sda4  Windows Root
├─ sda5  WinRE (500M)
├─ sda6  Linux Root
├─ sda7  swap
└─ sda8  Linux Home
```

My question is: Can I use the EFI system (where windows stores files for booting) partition to install grub and avoid having to make an extra boot partition?

Comment: The ESP (EFI System Partition) is not /boot. And yes, it can and should be used for all installed OSes in a multi-boot configuration.

Comment: UEFI systems need ESP - efi system partition as FAT32. Most desktops do not need a separate /boot partition which must be Linux format. But some server installs or LVM logical volumes may want or use a separate /boot partition. Your current sda1 looks more like a bios_grub partition which is unformatted and used only for BIOS boot with grub. If UEFI, you do not need nor want a bios_grub partition. Be sure to have good backups. And boot both Windows & Ubuntu installer flash drives in UEFI boot mode, so installs are UEFI.

Comment: Well, I used bios based PCs for a very long time, hence the partition layout, even on a UEFI system. In theory you say that I don't need the boot partition if I'm on a UEFI system, and grub can be installed in the root partition, right?